# Cannot access website without www

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, configuration

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I cannot seem to access my website without including the www prefix in the URL, otherwise I can access it fine. I have the following DNS records:

A: @ - directs to 000.000.000.000

CNAME: *.example.com - is an alias of example.com

And in my .conf file, I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The file should be working because I can access the site at www.example.com, so I'm not sure if there's a mistake in my Redirect or if it's something else, but I'm struggling to figure this out.

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: A wildcard CNAME to a zone apex is almost certainly not a good idea.

Comment: Please stop useless (and bad) obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

You have a CNAME record for "*.example.com" which only accounts for having a . in front of the domain with anything (including "www") preceding it, so it would work if you tried something like test.example.com. Make a new A record with @ in the field where you would put "www".

Comment: Why would I need to do that if I already have the A record?

Comment: @user4181107 You need 2 A records: 1 with "www" and 1 with "@", both pointing to the same IP.  You can keep your wildcard CNAME as is to catch everything else.  You can read more about it [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/2237/how-can-i-set-up-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain).

Comment: I can access the website fine using the "www" preceding the domain name. The problem is accessing the website without the "www". This solution feels like it's more intended to solve a problem where the website cannot be accessed using "www", or am I mistaken?

Comment: @user4181107 You're mistaken. I know what you're asking for and you're missing the "@" A record entry. That's what that type of entry is for - to access your top level domain without a need for a www prefix.

Comment: But I do have the "@" A record entry, and the CNAME record is a wildcard entry serving as an alias for that A record.

Comment: You said your @ record is pointing to 000.000.000.000. That's wrong.  It needs to be to the same IP as your www record

Comment: There is no indication in the question that there is a specific record for `www`.

Comment: @womble Didn't catch that but apparently there is one if it's working.  He's just missing a CORRECT "@" record it seems.

Comment: Presumably the wildcard CNAME is doing its job.  But without the actual domain name to poke against, we're all just guessing as to what's really going on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused... So what should my DNS records look like? And if it turns out that the DNS records are correct, what should be my next step to diagnose what is causing this issue?

Comment: True. Could just pull the records ourselves to see what's going on.

Comment: @user4181107 They SHOULD be: A record for www.example.com; A record for @example.com; CNAME for *.example.com. The 2 A records should point to the same IP and the CNAME should point to the www A record

Comment: I'll give that a try. What would you recommend my next steps be if that doesn't work?

Comment: FYI, you may have to wait for DNS propagation after you change these records.  I suggest lowering the TTL to as low as it allows until you get this working, in case you need further changes, so you don't have to wait long for changes to propagate. Then you can raise it at the end when things are finalized.

Comment: @user4181107 If that doesn't work, you'll need to tell us your actual domain name so we can look at the records ourselves.